# Wave REST API returns BAD REQUEST ERROR 400

Tags: rest-api, rest, einstein-analytics, saql

```
    public class SendWaveUsingRESTAPI {
     private final String clientId = 'xxxx';
     private final String clientSecret = 'xxx';
     private final String username = 'xxxxx';
     private final String password = 'xxxxxx';
     public class deserializeResponse
     {
        public String id;
        public String access_token;
     }
     public class deserializewaveresp
     {
        public String action;
        public String responseId;
        public String results;
        public String query;
        public String responseTime;
     }
     public void ReturnAccessToken()
     {
        String reqbody = 'grant_type=password&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret+'&username='+username+'&password='+password;
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setBody(reqbody);
        req.setMethod('POST');  
        req.setEndpoint('https://XXXXXX.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        system.debug('######access_token####'+res.getbody());
        deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        system.debug('@@@@access_token@@'+resp1);
        if(resp1.access_token!=null)
       {
           String endPoint ='https://XXXXXX.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/wave/query';
           String jsonstr ="{"query":"q = load \"datasetId/versionid\";\n+q = group q by ('Name','Wac.cc');\n+q = foreach q generate 'Name' as 'Name','Wac.cc' as 'Wac.cc', count() as 'count';\n+q = order q by ('Name' asc,'wac.cc' asc);\n+q = limit q 2;\\"}";
           Http h2 = new Http();
           HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
           req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' +resp1.access_token);
           req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
           req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
           req1.setBody(jsonstr);
           req1.setMethod('POST');
           req1.setEndpoint(endPoint);
           HttpResponse res1 = h2.send(req1);
           deserializewaveresp resp2 = (deserializewaveresp)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializewaveresp.class);
           system.debug('@@@RESPONSE@@'+resp2);
        }
      }
    }
```

I am trying to pass wave SAQL query to Wave REST API. But this is returning an error code:

> bad request error 400.

Can anyone know how the request body has to be given for the wave rest query resource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to sereilize the request body SAQL to json string.Now i am getting response